# LOAD CSV Relationships not properly matching to nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 files:

#### persons.csv

```
person
bob
boob
booboo
```

#### incident.csv

```
place,address,incident
the bowling alley, '501 mane st.', blocking lanes
house of bob, city park, peeing in public
rodeo bar, '77 sunset', bucking the bronco
```

#### day.csv

```
day
moonday
tuesday
wednesday
```

`Day.csv` is my relationship file. fi, I want bob at the rodeo bar on tuesday.
I load csv with headers// the person and incident files and create nodes successfully, but adding the relationships doesn't work for me in neo4j 3.5.6 no matter what combinations, including merge, match, create, optional match, etc. that I see suggested to this seemingly common issue, or docs solutions that I try. I'm getting errors, or (no changes, no records), or the creation of new nodes and properties in addition to the existing ones. Suggestions?

```
load csv with headers from "file:///day.csv" as line
MERGE (a:Person {person: line.person})
MERGE (b:Place{place: line.place, address: line.address, incident: line.incident, })
MERGE (a)-[:DAY {day:line.day}]->(b)
```

Tried match, merge, create...Match, create... left out props...except on day... etc...

Answer (score 1):

The `day.csv` file does not contain any data for the `person`, `place`, `address`, and `incident` fields. To execute your query, you'd need to add those fields to that CSV file.

Also, you should really only provide the minimum data needed to get the appropriate `Place` node. For example, if `Place` nodes have unique `place` properties, then omit the `address` and `incident` fields from `day.csv` (and from your Cypher code as well).

*By the way, you may also want to change the spelling for "moonday".*